# Problem with tag title

Tags: magento2, seo

[image: **enter image description here**]

How can i remove (or edit) from my store --> (- Gyps Light)
I can not understand how it was added, and especially where it took the name Gyps Light

magento 2.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it by following steps:
Login to admin and navigate to Content -> Design -> Configuration
Click on edit of your required theme
Navigate to HTML Head tab and remove the Page Title Suffix you are using as show in below screenshot.

[image]

***Note: It will take time reflect in google search as google take time to crawl***.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But why in spite of my field is still set by default, Gyps Light has been set up, which is the name of my category!

Comment: Did you migrate it from magento 1 to magento2. Somehow it copied to suffix field. Did you get the suffix field with that text?

Comment: Nothing migration , thanks for your help . I'm waiting google reindex. Have a nice day!

Comment: Welcome! Happy Coding.